# JSDoc auto-complete documentation in Eclipse is not working for Class.create()

Tags: javascript, eclipse, documentation, prototypejs, jsdoc

I have something like:

```
/**
* @class
*/
NS.MyAwesomeObject = Class.create();

NS.MyAwesomeObject.prototype = {
 /**
 * @param id - the id
 * @return - an alert dialog with an id
 */
 initialize : function(id){
    alert(id);
 }
}
```

Am I missing something? I get up to NS. -> auto-complete: MyAwesomeObject, but I want NS.MyAwesomeObject. -> auto-complete: initialize(id).

It works fine for other cases when I don't use Class.create(). I googled and the [solution](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/issues/detail?id=164) was to add @class, but that didn't work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works by me. Btw Eclipse doesn't have jsDoc 3 support.
With jsDoc 3 your code looks so:

```
var NS = {};

/** @class */
NS.MyAwesomeObject = Class.create(
    /** @lends NS.MyAwesomeObject.prototype */
    {
        /**
         * @constructs
         * @param {Number} id - the id
         * @returns {Void} - an alert dialog with an id
         */
        initialize:function (id) {
            alert(id);
        }
    });
```

The code completion for jsDoc 3 works only with WebStorm (or others Jetbrains products) now.

[Oo javascript code completion in any IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446896/oo-javascript-code-completion-in-any-ide/12469427#12469427) (Had problem with this either.)